# Banshee smooth start/pause playing?

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, music, banshee

Is there any plugin to make Banshee start playing, pause tracks smooth? Rhythmbox has such an option, but U can't find it in Banshee.

Answer (score 4):

There is no option to do this, as Banshee does not yet support crossfading.
See [Bug 524300](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524300) for more information.